# Generics, Guava Ordering.arbitrary()

Tags: java, generics, guava, comparator

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final Ordering<EmailTemplate> ARBITRARY_ORDERING = (Ordering)Ordering.arbitrary();

public static final Ordering<EmailTemplate> ORDER_BY_NAME = Ordering.natural().nullsFirst().onResultOf(GET_NAME);

public static final Ordering<EmailTemplate> ORDER_BY_NAME_SAFE = Ordering.allEqual().nullsFirst()
            .compound(ORDER_BY_NAME)
            .compound(ARBITRARY_ORDERING);
```

Here's the code a use to order EmailTemplate.
If i have a list of EmailTemplate i want the null elements of the list to appear at the beginning, then the elements with a null name, and then by natural name order, and if they have the same name, an arbitrary order.

---

Is it how i am supposed to do? It seems strange to start the comparator by "allEqual" i think...

I also wonder what's the best way to deal with the Ordering.arbitrary(), since it's a static method that returns Ordering. Is there any elegant way to use it? I don't really like this kind of useless, with warning, line:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final Ordering<EmailTemplate> ARBITRARY_ORDERING = (Ordering)Ordering.arbitrary();
```

---

By the way, the documentation says:

> Returns an arbitrary ordering over all objects, for which `compare(a,
>   b) == 0` implies `a == b` (identity equality). There is no meaning
>   whatsoever to the order imposed, but it is constant for the life of the VM.

Does this mean that my object being compared with this Ordering will never be garbage collected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the second question: no. Guava uses the identity hash codes of the objects to sort them arbitrarily.

Regarding the first question: I would use a comparison chain to sort by name, then by arbitrary order:

```
private class ByNameThenArbitrary implements Comparator<EmailTemplate> {
    @Override
    public int compare(EmailTemplate e1, EmailTemplate e2) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
                              .compare(e1.getName(), e2.getName(), Ordering.natural().nullsFirst(),
                              .compare(e1, e2, Ordering.arbitrary())
                              .result();
    }
}
```

Then I would create the real ordering to order the templates with nulls first:

```
private static final Ordering<EmailTemplate> ORDER = 
    Ordering.fromComparator(new ByNameThenArbitrary()).nullsFirst();
```

Not tested, though.

Comment: I don't really understand why it would be better to use a ComparisonChain or Ordering.compound(...) can you explain please?

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber: `ComparisonChain` is a powerful builder, you don't want use it when something simpler suffices. Here it seems to be appropriate, I'd maybe prepend `.compareFalseFirst(e1!=null, e2!=null)` and you're done, but what JB Nizet has done works most probably too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure, you're doing it too complicated:

- `Ordering.arbitrary()` works with any `Object` and the `compound` doesn't require to restrict it to `EmailTemplate`
- Saying `nullsFirst()` takes priority when `null` gets compared, and I'd suggest to apply it last
- You don't need to define multiple constants, it all should be easy

I'd go for

```
public static final Ordering<EmailTemplate> ORDER_BY_NAME_SAFE = Ordering
    .natural()
    .onResultOf(GET_NAME)
    .compound(Ordering.arbitrary())
    .nullsFirst();
```

but I haven't tested it.

---

What's confusing here, is the way how `compound` and `nullsFirst` work. With the former, `this` takes precedence, while with the latter testing for `null` wins. Both is logical:

- `compound` works left to right
- `nullsFirst` must first test for null, otherwise we'd get an expection

but taken together it's confusing.

---

> Does this mean that my object being compared with this Ordering will never be garbage collected?

No, it uses weak references. Whenever an object isn't referenced elsewhere, it can be garbage collected. This is no contradiction to "the ordering is constant for the life of the VM", since a no more existing object can't be compared anymore.

Note that `Ordering.arbitrary()` is indeed arbitrary and based on object's identity rather than on `equals`, which means that

```
 Ordering.arbitrary().compare(new String("a"), new String("a"))
```

doesn't return 0.

I wonder if an "equals-compatible arbitrary ordering" could be implemented.

Comment: I don't understand in your code how i can handle both the case where emailtemplate is null, and where emailtemplate.name is null. It seems you handle only one of the cases

Comment: Btw on your code, the "compound(Ordering.arbitrary())" doesn't compile because of generics

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber: 1. I see.... but you can easily handle `emailTemplate==null` in your `GET_NAME`. Maybe adding `nullsFirst` before `onResultOf` could help as well? 2. It *does* compile, at least in my Eclipse.

Comment: @maaartinus For your equals-compatible ordering, you can use: `Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Object::hashCode).compound((a, b) -> a.equals(b) ? 0 : Ordering.arbitrary().compare(a, b))`. That will use natural (integer order) ordering on the `hashCode()` method's return value, then check for `a.equals(b)` if the hash codes are the same, and arbitrary ordering if they aren't equal but their hash codes are.

Comment: @ShadowMan I'm afraid, this is wrong. Assume `a==b` and `c==d` and no other equalities. Compare `a` and `c` and get an arbitrary result, repeat for `b` and `d`. Now, you can have `a<c` and `d<b`, i.e., `a<c=d<b=a`, which is wrong. I'm assuming equals hashes, as they solve the majority of cases. IIRC I've spent some more time on this a few years ago and I may have found a solution, but if so, it was complicated.

Comment: Oh good point. It threw up a red flag to me but I couldn't come up with any scenario that made it fail. But I didn't think to bring `c==d` into the equation. That explains why an arbitrary + equals relationship can't work. If everything used in the equals isn't also used in determining its order, then the contract cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: You could write your own that handles equals and arbitrary by doing nearly the same things that guava is doing but you'll have to rewrite it yourself. You'd just need to use the actual `hashCode()` implementation instead of the `Object` implementation that guava is using. In that case, the first comparison made against (a or b) and (c or d) would determine the result of any future comparisons. When a is added to the map, it is given a number, when b is added later, it gets the same number (technically it isn't added, since it was equal to a) and the same for c and d, so the contract is happy.